# Can't Remove Child From LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I can only remove 1 view from the imgLayout. When it loops more than 1 time, it will skip the removing part. I don't know why this is. For some reason it says that the child I wan't to remove is null then. Plz look at the image and help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all: Paste the code in the question instead of a image of it.

Second, the answer:
Since you are looping from 0...n when you remove one of those the size of childs will have n-1, thats why you will remove wrong Views and not remove views outside of the range if you removed previously ones.

A solution is to loop from n...0 so you will remove the last ones first and the index will keep intact.

So your `for` will be:

```
for(int k = imageURIList.size() - 1; k > 0; k--) {
```

Comment: I don't really understand how I should write it. Can you please write it for me so I understand?